# Am I accessing the DOM correctly in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

Am I accessing the DOM correctly in Vue.js? My task is such that when I click on the title, a form appears and I can edit the record in it.  To cancel, press ESC, and to save, press ENTER.

my `template`:

```
<div v-for="(note, i) in notes" :key="i">
    <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title" @click="editNote($event, i)">{{note.title}}</h5>
        <input type="hidden">
    </div>
</div>
```

my `script`:

```
editNote (event, i){
    let parent = event.target,
        block = parent.closest('.card-body'),
        input = block.querySelector('input'),
        text = parent.textContent;
    input.type = "text"
    input.value = text
    parent.style.display = "none"
    input.onkeydown = (e) =>{
        if (e.keyCode == 27){
            input.type = "hidden"
            parent.style.display = "block"
        }
        else if (e.keyCode == 13){
            input.type = "hidden"
            parent.style.display = "block"
            parent.textContent = input.value
            this.notes[i].title = input.value
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You seem to be doing way too much with the DOM here and not enough with Vue's template. The input should be hidden or shown using a `v-if` directive. The `@click` should just set a flag which that `v-if` reacts to. For key codes, use `v-on`: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is a solution, but you can do much better by using `v-if`, `v-model` and `@keypress`.

With `v-if` you can check whether a specific variable is true or not. With that you can manipulate your `h5` and `input` by setting the variable in `editNote` to `true`. This is how you can get rid of the `display` CSS manipulation.

With `@keypress` in the `input` tag, you can get rid of the `keydown` event and enter your solution there.

With the `v-model` you can easily get the value whenever someone enters something in the `input`. Also, you can get directly the value of the input.

Checkout these links for more:

[v-model](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html)

[v-if](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html)

[event handling](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  But it didn't really help me.
What I've done?
 - <input v-if = "edit" type = "text">
 - in data created a variable: edit: true
Bottom line, I have an input in all records, and I only need the appearance of an input for a specific record.

Comment: @Max Then give each input a unique condition, e.g. `v-if="edit == i"`, and let `@click` set `edit = i`…

Comment: What exactly do you mean?